# How to give current site endpoint url to a javawebstart client application

Tags: java, web-services, java-web-start, endpoint

Which is the best way to give a javawebstart client a webservice url?
Currently I have a JWS Client app that need to reach the Webserver from where the JNLP resides to call its Webservice.
I would like, despite the host where its deployed, to inform the client the current web host dinamically.
Given that the package is signed and this same package should be deployed in all development chain's servers I am wondering how can it be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the URL relative to the [code base](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#getCodeBase--) of the application.

```
URL codeBase = basicService.getCodeBase();
// ..do stuff with code base info.
```